# How to save ggplot with an added logo to it while preserving image quality

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to save this `ggplot2` chart below using the `ggsave` function after I've added a logo to it

```
# Load packages and dataset
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)

data(mpg, package="ggplot2")

# Load a logo from Github

logo <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")

# Plot Code

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_count(col="tomato3", show.legend=F)

# Add logo to plot

grid::grid.raster(logo, x = 0.04, y = 0.03, just = c('left', 'bottom'), width = unit(1, 'inches'))
```

However, when I try to save the plot using `ggsave`, it saves the plot without the logo. Any way to overcome this and have the logo appear in the saved image?

```
ggsave('Plot.tiff',width =10,height = 6, device = 'tiff', dpi = 700)
```

Comment: Looks like you need [image_composite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#Graphics_device)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an incredibly clunky way by inserting the raster at the `gtable` level and then re-inserting the gtable as a custom annotation. I'm sorry I couldn't find a more succinct way.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.11.57
#> Enabled features: cairo, freetype, fftw, ghostscript, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fontconfig, x11

data(mpg, package="ggplot2")

# Load a logo from Github

logo <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")

# Plot Code

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_count(col="tomato3", show.legend=F)
# Convert to gtable
g <- ggplotGrob(g)

# Save logo as grob
grob <- grid::rasterGrob(logo, x = 0.04, y = 0.03, just = c('left', 'bottom'), 
                         width = unit(1, 'inches'))


# Insert grob in gtable
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(
  g, grob, t = 1, l = 1, b = dim(g)[1], r = dim(g)[2]
)

# Add old plot as annotation to new plot with void theme
ggplot() +
  annotation_custom(g) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

```r
ggsave('Plot.tiff',width =10,height = 6, device = 'tiff', dpi = 700)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer, but I genuinely think @tjebo's answer is the better way to solve this. I'd have no bad feelings if you accepted his answer instead.

Answer (score 6):

Or just use the old fashioned way, by creating a device first

```
png()
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_count(col="tomato3", show.legend=F)
grid::grid.raster(logo, x = 0.04, y = 0.03, just = c('left', 'bottom'), width = unit(1, 'inches'))
dev.off()
```

you can find a small paragraph in ?ggsave, section Saving images without ggsave()

Comment: Yeah that is probably the better way!